# The sequence T is defined by $T_n = n! + 2, n \geq 1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

For the sequence $T$ defined by

$T_n = n! + 2, n \geq 1$

Question: Is $T$ increasing?

Please provide your comments on if this is correct. Thanks.

Let n = 1

$$T_1 = 1 \cdot 1 + 2 = 3$$
$$T_2 = 2 \cdot 3 + 2 = 8$$
$$T_3 = 3 \cdot 8 + 2 = 26$$
$$T_4 = 4 \cdot 26 + 2 = 106$$

Answer: T *is* increasing

Comment: What? Your inequalities test whether it is decreasing and increasing, both strictly and non-strictly.

Comment: $$T_4 = 4! + 2 = 24+2=26 \\ 
T_5 = 5! + 2 = 120 + 2 = 122 \\ $$

How did you get your $T_i$'s? What am I missing?

Comment: @MarkLao the condition was $ n\geq 1 $ so I started passing in values starting with 1 to $n$

Comment: I mean, why is $T_4=106$ and not 26?

Comment: @MarkLao well if I did it correctly n is currently 4. $4 \cdot 26 = 104 + 2 = 106$. I also referenced this chart to the right here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial and having added 2 to each line gave me these numbers.

Comment: Using the pattern you used, what will be $T_5$?

Comment: @MarkLao The output should be 132.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$T$ is increasing, each term is larger than the previous one.  To see this, look at

$$T_{n+1}-T_n=((n+1)!+2)-(n!+2).$$

Comment: I really did miss the simplicity of that. Thank you sir.

Comment: It's easy to over think here.